# Why doesn't multiple on_message events work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Why can't I have multiple `on_message` events?

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('in on_ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("in on_message #1")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("in on_message #2")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("in on_message #3")

client.run("TOKEN")
```

For example, if I typed anything in discord, it's always only the last `on_message` that gets triggered. How can I get all three to work?

Answer (score 10):

### It's not possible with the native `Client`

You can only have *one* `on_message`, if you have multiple, only the last one will be called for the `on_message` event. You'll just need to combine your three `on_message`.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("in on_message #1")
    print("in on_message #2")
    print("in on_message #3")

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Like any Python variable/function (unless the decorator stores your function, `@client.event` does it by keeping only the most recent callback), if multiple names are the same, the most recently will be kept, and all others will get overwritten.

This is a simple example I wrote to give you a broad understanding of how events in discord.py work (note: the actual code isn't exactly like this, as it's rewritten and significantly reduced).

```
class Client:
    def event(self, func):               
        if func.__name__ == "on_message":
            self.on_message_handle = func
            return func

    def receive_message(self, msg):
        func = getattr(self, "on_message_handle", None)
        if func is not None:
            func(msg)
        else:
            self.process_commands(msg)

client = Client()

@client.event
def on_message(msg):
    print("in on_message #1")

@client.event
def on_message(msg):
    print("in on_message #2")

client.receive_message("hello")
# "in on_message #2"
```

As you can see `client.event` only keep one instance of `on_message`.

---

### You can with `Bot` instances

Alternatively, if you're using the `ext.commands` extension of discord.py, there is a native way to have multiple `on_message` callbacks. You do so by using defining them as a `listener`. You can have at most one `on_message` event, and infinite amounts of `on_message` listeners.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('.')

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    print("in on_message #1")
    await bot.process_commands(msg)  # so `Command` instances will still get called


@bot.listen()
async def on_message(msg):
    print("in on_message #2")


@bot.listen()
async def on_message(msg):
    print("in on_message #3")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

When a message is received, all `on_message #1-3` will all get printed.

Answer (score 1):

In python, functions are just objects.

```
>>> def foo():
...     print ("hi")
```

defines an object called `foo`, You can see this using a Python shell.

```
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x...>
>>> foo()
hi
```

If you define a new method after, or redefine the variable `foo`, you lose access to the initial function.

```
>>> foo = "hi"
>>> foo
hi
>>> foo()
Traceback ...:
    file "<stdin>" ...
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How the `@client.event` decorator works is it tells your client that new messages should be piped into the messages, and well, if the method gets redefined, it means the old method is lost.

```
>>> @bot.event
... async def on_message(m):
...     print(1)
...
>>> bot.on_message(None) # @bot.event makes the bot define it's own method
1
>>> @bot.event
... async def on_message(m):
...     print(2)
...
>>> bot.on_message(None) # bot's own method was redefined.
2
```