# one discord bot command makes other command not working

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

```
import asyncio
import discord

client = discord.Client()


token = "########################"


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as ") 
    print(client.user.name)
    print("===========")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith('!디엠 '):
        if (str(message.author.id) != "451744624965582848"):
            await message.channel.send(":no_entry_sign:  최고 관리자만 전체 DM을 요청할 수 있어요.")
            return None

        DM내용 = message.content.lower()[4:]
        for guild in client.guilds:
            members = guild.members
            for member in members:
                if member.bot is True:
                    continue
                channel = await member.create_dm()
                embed = discord.Embed(title='  전체 공지', color = FFFF33)
                embed.add_field(name=' 에서 발송된 DM입니다.', value=DM내용, inline=False)
                embed.set_footer(text="OWS SHOP DM봇")
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await message.channel.send('메세지가 성공적으로 전달되었어요.')

    await client.process_commands(message)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='환영합니다', colour = discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.add_field(name=f'{member.name}님, OWS SHOP의 모든 제품을 마음껏 둘러보세요!', value="모든 구매 문의는 <@451744624965582848>에게 주시면 감사하겠습니다.", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="OWS SHOP 인사봇")
    await client.get_channel(717379135609110615).send(embed=embed)

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='안녕히 가세요', colour = discord.Colour.red())
    embed.add_field(name=f'{member.name}님이 나가셨어요.', value="다음에 또 와주시면 감사하겠습니다!", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="OWS SHOP 인사봇")
    await client.get_channel(717379135609110615).send(embed=embed)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (str(message.channel.id) == "717379135835603005"):
        if (message.content.find("@everyone") != -1):
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(":no_entry_sign:  <@"+str(message.author.id)+">님, 중고장터에서는 everyone을 사용하실 수 없어요.")

        else:
            if (message.content.find("@here") != -1):
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(":no_entry_sign:  <@"+str(message.author.id)+">님, 중고장터에서는 here을 사용하실 수 없어요.")


client.run(token)
```

I made "DM ALL USERS IN SERVER" and "Welcome, goodbye message" and "Detect everyone or here and delete and warn" bot with Discord.py. "Detect everyone or here and delete and warn" feature is works, but "DM ALL USERS IN SERVER" Feature is not works.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (str(message.channel.id) == "717379135835603005"):
        if (message.content.find("@everyone") != -1):
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(":no_entry_sign:  <@"+str(message.author.id)+">님, 중고장터에서는 everyone을 사용하실 수 없어요.")

        else:
            if (message.content.find("@here") != -1):
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(":no_entry_sign:  <@"+str(message.author.id)+">님, 중고장터에서는 here을 사용하실 수 없어요.")
```

This part works well, but

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith('!디엠 '):
        if (str(message.author.id) != "451744624965582848"):
            await message.channel.send(":no_entry_sign:  최고 관리자만 전체 DM을 요청할 수 있어요.")
            return None

        DM내용 = message.content.lower()[4:]
        for guild in client.guilds:
            members = guild.members
            for member in members:
                if member.bot is True:
                    continue
                channel = await member.create_dm()
                embed = discord.Embed(title='  전체 공지', color = FFFF33)
                embed.add_field(name=' 에서 발송된 DM입니다.', value=DM내용, inline=False)
                embed.set_footer(text="OWS SHOP DM봇")
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await message.channel.send('메세지가 성공적으로 전달되었어요.')

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

This part doesn't works well.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (str(message.channel.id) == "717379135835603005"):
        if (message.content.find("@everyone") != -1):
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(":no_entry_sign:  <@"+str(message.author.id)+">님, 중고장터에서는 everyone을 사용하실 수 없어요.")

        else:
            if (message.content.find("@here") != -1):
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(":no_entry_sign:  <@"+str(message.author.id)+">님, 중고장터에서는 here을 사용하실 수 없어요.")
```

If I delete this part, (!디엠) works well. What is problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have **one** of each event in your code when you're using `discord.Client()`. There's no need to have multiple - whatever you can do in multiple events, you can also do in one. Use `if`/`elif` statements.

If you do include multiple events, the one that was most recently defined/registered will be the "active" one.

I'd recommend looking into creating commands with command decorators, as it's a lot more convenient than cramming them all into an `on_message` event;

```py
@client.command(name="디엠") # the string contents is what the command will be in discord
async def mycmd(ctx): # try to avoid having non-ASCII characters as identifiers
    if ctx.author.id != 451744624965582848: # IDs are ints in rewrite, no need to convert to str
        await ctx.send(":no_entry_sign:  최고 관리자만 전체 DM을 요청할 수 있어요.")
    else:
        # rest of the command's code

@client.command()
async def othercmd(ctx): # same concept applies if you want multiple commands
    # some more code here

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.channel.id == 717379135835603005: # same deal here with the IDs
        # rest of the code
    elif other_expression == "something else":
        # do some other stuff
    # etc.
```

---

**References:**

- [Multiple events with a `Bot` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50165400/7808223)
- [Major changes in rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) - See how IDs are `int`s.
- [Using command decorators](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#commands)
- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)

Answer (score 0):

At the very end of the on_message event, add await client.process_commands(message)