# Random.choice inside an embed in discord.py not working

Tags: python, discord.py

I did the same with client.command and it worked. However, I wanted to use ?rate me instead of ?rateme and hence decided to using on_message. I don't see anything wrong with my code, and its executing without any errors. But when I type ?rate me in discord, nothing fires. Would be grateful if someone could help me figure out what's wrong.

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('?rate me'):
        async with message.channel.typing():
            variable_list =[
                '1',
                '2',
                '3',
                '4'
            ]

            embed = discord.Embed(colour=0xc81f9f,
                title="Rating",
                description=f"{message.author.mention} is a {(random.choice(variable_list))}"
            )
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{message.guild.name}")
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: description=f"{message.author.mention} is a {(random.choice(variable_list))}") Replace with this, You had a bracket without any reason.

Comment: try printing something inside the on_message and see if that works.

Comment: have you imported random?

Comment: @AdityaTomar Yes, I have imported random.

Comment: @Karan Sorry, I don't see what change did you make in the statement.

Comment: @Ceres tried this ```async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('?rate me'):
        print('working!')``` but this doesn't seem to print anything.

Comment: all other commands and events in my bot seem to be working fine, except for this one. i even tried the textbook example ```@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "pong":
        await message.channel.send('ping')``` which is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have not marked your function as an `event`.
Please use `@client.event` `@bot.event` or `@commands.Cog.listener`.
Without this definition it will not work.
I would also recommend you to rebuild the code a bit to detect the error faster. My code looks like this:

```py
import discord
import random

@client.event / @bot.event / @commands.Cog.listener # Make it as an event that fires if the conditions are True
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("?rate me"):
        async with message.channel.typing():
            variable_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

            embed = discord.Embed(color=0xc81f9f,
                                  title="Rating")
            embed.description = f"{message.author.mention} is a {(random.choice(variable_list))}" # Set description
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{message.guild.name}")
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

***If you already have an existing `on_message` event simply put the code without the first part into the existing event and then you have:***

```py
    if message.content.startswith("?rate me"):
        async with message.channel.typing():
            variable_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

            embed = discord.Embed(color=0xc81f9f,
                                  title="Rating")
            embed.description = f"{message.author.mention} is a {(random.choice(variable_list))}" # Set description
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{message.guild.name}")
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

(This is because we can't have more than one `on_message`-event here.)

Comment: I did use the @client.event just like I used it with all the other events that seem to be working fine. Except for this one. I even copy pasted your entire code, but it doesn't seem to work. The on_ready fires and then nothing happens.

Comment: Do you already have an `on_message` event in your code?

Comment: Ah yes, I do. I have an on_message event that returns a random joke. Am I not supposed to have more than one on_message event in my code?

Comment: No, I would not recommend that. Put the code I sent into the existing event. (See the code at the end of my answer)

Comment: Damn, yeah, I just did that and it worked. But why can we not use more than one on_message event when we can use more than one @client.command? Also, currently, the code looks messy. Can I write the other on_message event in another py file and call it on my main file? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: This should answer your question: [Why can't we have multiple on_message events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165120/why-doesnt-multiple-on-message-events-work). You can indeed write your `events`  into another file but I would open another question for that or first have a look at the docs/some videos as this is not part of the question anymore.