# Discord bot codes not working (python). How can I fix it?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I recently started coding and decided a good, fun way to learn would be to make a Discord bot. So I did some coding, learnt from a Youtube video and it was all going well but now none of my codes are working and the bot is basically useless. Could someone please look at this code and tell me what's wro

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hi!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))


sad_words = ["sad","alone","scared","depressed","SAD","Sad"]

starter_encouragements = [
  "You got this. I know you do ",
  "I know it's hard, but you'll get through this :)",
]

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return(quote)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  msg = message.content

  if message.content.startswith('inspire'):
    quote = get_quote()
    await message.channel.send(quote)

  if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(starter_encouragements))


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Thanks so much

Comment: I don't want to be rude but the correct term would be `code` not `codes`, code in the context of programming is considered an uncountable noun such as `sand` or `water`. you don't say `I have some sands` do you? same here.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `on_message` events unfortunately do not work.

You can only have one event at a time, so you have to combine the events. This would look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('Hello'): # First event
        await message.channel.send('Hi!')
   
    [Shortened]

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    [Shortened]
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(starter_encouragements)) # Last event
```

I would also remove your second `on_ready` event as it is useless.

What you can indeed have is multiple `client.command()` functions but this does not count for events.
Maybe also have a look at the following post: [Why multiple on_message events will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165120/why-doesnt-multiple-on-message-events-work#:%7E:text=commands%20extension%20of%20discord.py,infinite%20amounts%20of%20on_message%20listeners.&text=When%20a%20message%20is%20received,3%20will%20all%20get%20printed.)