# event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro' error discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a bot for a new server and I keep getting this error, I'm fairly new to python and coding in general so any help is appreciated.

event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro' error discord.py

When I post this is saying it looks like my post is mostly code so im just going to type random things until it lets me post it. I have a pretty cool dog, he's very cute and he's the goodest boy to ever be good :)

Below is the code where I'm getting the error

```
@client.event
 

    
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
    .format(client))
```

And below is my full code

```
    import discord


client = discord.Client

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
    .format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('>Hello Sylas'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello there!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('>Is Dobbie cool?'):
        await message.channel.send('Yes, he is the goodest boy!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('>Hey Sylas'):
        if str(message.author) in ["Trax#8949"]:
            await message.channel.send('Hey Trax!')



@client.event
async def on_message(message):  
    if message.author == client.user:
        return        
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.content.startswith('>'):
     async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
      await member.ban(reason = reason)





 













client.run('my token :)')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to get a high-quality response as fast as possible, please do not type gibberish just to pass the question content requirement. While your dog seems nice, it does not help at all, and it would be much more useful to describe your problem in high detail. With that, it is also not necessary to post the entirety of your code, since Stack Overflow on requires minimal code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: You got a bit much on_message functions.. Maybe you should firstly put them all together in on function and look if it then works

Comment: try client = discord.Client()

Comment: Referring to the post linked at the end of @Dominik's post, I would highly recommend using the discord.ext.commands bot instead of discord.client(). I use that for my bot at the moment and it makes things quite a lot simpler. It is clear that you want a bunch of different on_messages to split your code up. You can do that with the listeners as mentioned in the linked post. just make sure to put `await bot.process_commands(message)` at the end of the original on_message if you want commands to still work (if you make any).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `on_message` events will **not** work.

You can only have one event at a time, so you have to combine the events. This would look like this:

```py
client = discord.Client() # Added brackets

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('>Hey Sylas'):
        if str(message.author) in ["Trax#8949"]:
            await message.channel.send('Hey Trax!') # First event

    [Shortened]

    if message.content.startswith('>ban'):
      await member.ban(reason = reason) # Last event
```

You can have multiple `client.command()` "functions" but this does not count for events.

***A post that explains it pretty well: [Why multiple on_message events will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165120/why-doesnt-multiple-on-message-events-work#:%7E:text=commands%20extension%20of%20discord.py,infinite%20amounts%20of%20on_message%20listeners.&text=When%20a%20message%20is%20received,3%20will%20all%20get%20printed.)***

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import discord


client = discord.Client

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
    .format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    elif message.content.startswith('>Hello Sylas'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello there!')

    elif message.content.startswith('>Is Dobbie cool?'):
        await message.channel.send('Yes, he is the goodest boy!')

    elif message.content.startswith('>Hey Sylas'):
        if str(message.author) == "Trax#8949":
            await message.channel.send('Hey Trax!')

    elif message.content.startswith('>ban'): # You should restrict that to specific roles
        await member.ban(reason = reason)


client.run('now its my token :)')
```

What I've done:

- put all `on_message` in **one** `on_message`
- changed to `">ban"` instead of using an uncalled function in it
- changed `"in ['Trax']"` to `"== 'Trax'"`
- added `elif`s