# How to make a discord bot kick someone when they say a trigger word

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How to make a discord bot kick someone when they say a trigger word? Like for example when someone says 'idiot' they will get kicked from the server.

Here is what I tried:

```
**import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready?")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find("lol") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("HI!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find('matei') != -1:
        await kick('minionulLuiMatei#5893')
        return




client.run(token)**
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** have multiple `on_message` events. You have to form them into one.

***A post that explains it pretty well: [Why multiple on_message events will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165120/why-doesnt-multiple-on-message-events-work#:%7E:text=commands%20extension%20of%20discord.py,infinite%20amounts%20of%20on_message%20listeners.&text=When%20a%20message%20is%20received,3%20will%20all%20get%20printed.)***

Now to your question. You can use two methods to filter the words and kick a member:

***First method:*** Filters all messages and looks to see if the word `Idiot` appears at any point in a sentence.

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if "Idiot" in message.content:
```

***Second method:***
Checks if the word `Idiot` only appears at the beginning of the sentence.

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("Idiot"):
```

Then to kick a member you use the following function:

```py
await message.author.kick(reason=None)
```

Your entire code would be:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "Idiot" in message.content: # Method 1
        await message.author.kick(reason=None) # Kick the author of the message, reason is optional

    if message.content.startswith("Idiot"): # Method 2
       await message.author.kick(reason=None)
```